# Calling a method that has autowired values

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a method where I am injecting a value to an argument of the method. How can I call the checkHealth without passing in an argument that will overwrite the value value being injected?

```
private Health checkHealth(@Qualifier("myRestTemplate") RestTemplate restTemplate) {

}

@Bean(name = "myRestTemplate")
public RestTemplate myRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    return builder
        .rootUri(uri)
        .basicAuthentication("", "")
        .build();
}
```

Comment: Are you looking for `checkHealth(myRestTemplate())`? If not, could you add more details to the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you cannot! Note that Spring's annotations work in its Spring's context and not when you manually try to do something. What it means is that, the injection will effectively happen if and only if Spring invokes the method `checkHealth()` and not when you call this method.
In your case, you do not need to pass in the argument. Simply call `myRestTemplate()` inside `checkHealth()` as:

```
private Health checkHealth() {
   final RestTemplate template = myRestTemplate();
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Prashant. In my case , I do not want a new RestTemplate object to be created each time checkhealth method is called. I was trying to use Spring's singleton implementation with the help of beans - looks I have to do it myself in this case.

Comment: You are welcome. You can, however, use `Lombok` extension called `lombok-pg` to create a Singleton class with the aptly named annotation - `@Singleton` :)

Answer (score 0):

For your scenario to work, inject `myRestTemplate` as a field:

```
@Service
public class HealthServiceImpl implements HealthService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myRestTemplate") 
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    private Health checkHealth() {
         // do something with restTemplate
    }
}
```

Otherwise, check @Prashant's answer on why injecting it as a method parameter does not work.

Comment: New code should use constructor injection wherever possible.

Comment: if I autowire the value at field level , the value of resttemplate is null in the checkHealth method.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing the below -

```
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

private Health checkHealth() {
            ResponseEntity<String> response
              = this.restTemplate.getForEntity(resourceUrl, String.class);
}

@Postconstruct
public RestTemplate myRestTemplate() {
    RestTemplateBuilder builder = new RestTemplateBuilder();
    return builder
        .rootUri(uri)
        .basicAuthentication("", "")
        .build();
}
```